# I have a sticky navbar (search bar) but it still overlaps with the contents of the page when you scroll down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wonder how I can have the search bar (not the top navigation bar) not overlap with the page contents when you scroll down the page. Please note, I have a navigation bar and a search bar, what I am **referring** to in this issue is the **search bar (the sticky bar)** I.e. I don’t intend to have the top navigation bar sticky.

**Desired Outcome: to have the search bar on top of contents when the page is scrolled down instead of it overlapping with the contents of the page**

Things I tried: see in codeply, link below ⬇️.

See code in codeply:
https://codeply.com/v/1vpjO4BD6h

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Whenever you post a question please try to add the minimum amount of code that is required to understand the problem directly in the question instead of sharing a link it will be more helpful for future solution seekers.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `z-index` value to your `.sticky` class

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99; // z-index value should be heigher the content z-index if any.
}
```

Hope this is what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Why 99? and what about left?

Comment: @sheriffderek I just meant to add a `z-index` higher than everything else that should go under it.

Comment: Well, if you put it in the source order (below) you would need to do that / and also '2' or '10' would work, right?

Answer (score 0):

xx101. Can you create a really simple example of this? Maybe in a js fiddle like this? ->

```
<header>header</header>

<main>
  <section>main content stuff?</section>

  <aside>
    sidebar
  
    <div class="field">
      <label for="x">Search</label>
      <input type="search">
    </div>
   
  </aside>
</main>
```

.

```
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 2px;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 200vh; /* for example */
}

.field {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/sq97ygvo/

Hopefully - this example can explain how to create the minimum example. : )